# Biconjugate formula in non-separated locally convex spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I have a locally convex space $X$ with topological dual $X^*$ and coupling $\langle x,x^* \rangle:=x^*(x),\ x\in X,\ x^*\in X^*$.

For $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ one defines its convex conjugate by $f^*(x^*):=\sup\{\langle x,x^* \rangle-f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ and similarly for $g:X^*\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ one defines its convex conjugate by $g^*(x):=\sup\{\langle x,x^* \rangle-g(x^*)\mid x^*\in X^*\}$.

The biconjugate formula states that for a proper convex lower semicontinuous  $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ one has $f^{**}=f$.

The proof we went over in class is based on $X$ being Hausdorff separated and relies on separation theorems for the epigraph.

My question is whether the biconjugate formula holds when the space $X$ is NOT Hausdorff separated?

Comment: What if you consider the trivial topology on $X$?

Comment: @PhoemueX And by trivial topology on $X$ you mean what topology?

Comment: The one where only $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open.

Comment: @PhoemueX  First I need to verify that the coarse topology is linear and locally convex.